# JSON.parse returning undefined on my string

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

I have a returned string from my server and I want to parse it into a JSON object, the following is the string and what I am doing :

```
stringToParse = "\"{'female': 16, 'brand': 75, 'male': 8}\""
dataJson = JSON.parse(stringToParse)
console.log(dataJson)
console.log(dataJson.male)
```

I'm getting this as output :

```
{'female': 16, 'brand': 75, 'male': 8}
undefined
```

so I can't access the male, female, and brand objects within the JSON.

Comment: The `dataJson` is a string

Comment: how could it be,isn't the JSON.parse returns a JSON object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

correct json to be parsed should be

```
stringToParse = '{"female": 16, "brand": 75, "male": 8}'
```

you need to alter the code at your server to return data in this manner, or handle it in your js file.

This code works

```
let stringToParse = '{"female": 16, "brand": 75, "male": 8}'
dataJson = JSON.parse(stringToParse)
console.log(dataJson)
console.log(dataJson.male)
```

If, though, you can't alter the original `stringToParse`, then try this in order to parse it at js

```
let stringToParse = "\"{'female': 16, 'brand': 75, 'male': 8}\""
JSON.parse(stringToParse.replace(/\"/g, '').replace(/'/g, '"'))
```

Comment: really hard to change the server's side, you know how I can easily switch to that in JS?

Comment: the easiest solution would be to double parse it `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(stringToParse))`

Comment: Updated my answer with that

Comment: @FahdLyousfi check my updated answer. I think `JSON.parse(stringToParse.replace(/\"/g, '').replace(/'/g, '"'))` will do the trick

Comment: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @FahdLyousfi i tried it in console and it works `let stringToParse = "\"{'female': 16, 'brand': 75, 'male': 8}\""
JSON.parse(stringToParse.replace(/\"/g, '').replace(/'/g, '"'))`

Comment: @FahdLyousfi if you copy/paste the code snippet i just posted (with a semicolon of course :) between the commands) it should work.

Comment: my bad, I was still using the double parse, your latest solution works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: check my solution

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with you string I think those extra quotation marks are useless. The JSON parser things that you providing him with a string "{"female": 16, "brand": 75, "male": 8}" and it parses it as string so you see the console.log result `{"female": 16, "brand": 75, "male": 8}` but it is not an objet the whole thing is a string. Remove extra quotation marks and it will think it is an object.

```js
stringToParse = '{"female": 16, "brand": 75, "male": 8}'
dataJson = JSON.parse(stringToParse)
console.log(dataJson)
console.log(dataJson.male)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json string is invalid format. In JSON, keys must be strings written with double quotes not in single quotes. e.g. {"male":16}. Try to read this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp. So below is the correct answer :

```
stringToParse = '{"female": 16, "brand": 75, "male": 8}'
dataJson = JSON.parse(stringToParse)
console.log(dataJson)
console.log(dataJson.male)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second line parse like this

```
stringToParse = "\"{'female': 16, 'brand': 75, 'male': 8}\""
dataJson = JSON.parse(stringToParse.replace(/\"/g, '').replace(/'/g, '"'))
```

```js
stringToParse = "\"{'female': 16, 'brand': 75, 'male': 8}\""
dataJson = JSON.parse(stringToParse.replace(/\"/g, '').replace(/'/g, '"'))
console.log(dataJson)
console.log(dataJson.male)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by using:

```
dataJson  = JSON.parse(decodeURI(stringToParse));
```

here is a reference to it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI